# SIGPIPE Exception

Tags: cocoa

I am developing an application in cocoa which consists of a client part written in java listens for a request from server (like reading some songs or files from client machine) sometimes this works fine but some times an Exception like "Recieved Signal SIGPIPE" occurs .I have no idea about this exception and how to handle this
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is the server written in Cocoa? If the client is Cocoa and Java, I hope you're using JNI, because the Cocoa-Java bridge (i.e., Cocoa classes as Java classes) is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

SIGPIPE means you attempted to write to a pipe, but nobody holds the read end. You closed your read end, and either you didn't create a child process before doing that or the child process has also closed its read end.

Comment: You can also set `SIGPIPE` to `SIG_IGN` and have `write()` or `send()` fail with `errno = EPIPE`.  I like this a lot better.

Answer (score -1):

`SIGPIPE` means that the other process has terminated.

Comment: Not exactly. In fact, it's not even necessary to have another process.